# Facebook Graph API: Can't get user gender using curl

Tags: curl, facebook-graph-api, command-line, facebook-php-sdk

I used the following command:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=gender,email,id,name,likes,birthday&access_token=XXX"
```

But the response I get doesn't have the field `gender`

```
{"email":"XXX\u0040gmail.com","id":"XXX","name":"XXX","likes":{"data":[{...}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"XXX","after":"XX"}}},"birthday":"XX\/XX\/XXXX"}
```

My APP is in development state and `user_gender` permission is enabled as well as `user_birthday`. I got access token by using PHP SDK.

```
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_url, array(
        'email',
        'user_birthday',
        'gender',
        'user_location',
        'user_likes'
    ));
```

Comment: What does the account in question have set as their gender in their Facebook profile?

Comment: @04FS Male and I have "Show in my timeline" checked in Facebook profile configuration

Comment: The permission is named `user_gender`, not gender …

Comment: @04FS Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under the permissions, put `user_gender`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22483438)

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the user did everything right and was missing just this piece, as I retraced his steps. If you look at the reply to @04FS comment, you will see the author was missing this.